# Data driven testing with different elements eg Katalon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, data-driven, katalon

I have used basic data-driven testing to populate fields in Katalon scripts but how do I supply values (in Excel) to click checkboxes and radio buttons, please? Eg where one instance of the script requires a 'true' value, the next run requires 'false'.

What should Katalon action be?

Tutorials only seem to cover basics (eg text into user/password fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IF ELSE condition for check/Uncheck the checkbox same as for radio button also.
In Excel store the Checkbox/radio button column value as 1/0
if 1- check 0-uncheck

```
 if(findTestData('UserGroup').getValue('Name',3)==1)
    {
       For Radio/Checkbox
       write a code to click
    }else{
       For Checkbox 
       write a code to uncheck
    }
```

Comment: if its work fine,please vote and press the tick

Answer (score 0):

Link used for Testing https://demo.nopcommerce.com/register?returnUrl=%2F

Excel File name is 'UseRadiobutton'.
Testing for 'Gender' Radio Button

```
if(findTestData('UseRadiobutton').getValue('Gender',row)==M)
    {
       WebUI.click(findTestObject('UseRadiobutton/Page_nopCommerce demo store Register/input_male_Gender'))
    }else{
       WebUI.click(findTestObject('UseRadiobutton/Page_nopCommerce demo store Register/input_female_Gender'))
    }
```